# Ceph Object Storage Supported AWS S3 SDK .NET4.5?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, ceph, object-storage

Is CEPH Object Gateway S3 API fully compatible with AWS S3 SDK .NET4.5 (AWSSDK.Core.dll / AWSSDK.S3.dll ?

I'm having error with PutObject : "Error making request with Error Code EntityTooLarge and Http Status Code BadRequest. No further error information was returned by the service." It run well in the pass release with dll name: AWSSDK.dll.

Comment: If it was working before consider opening an issue here https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net although it might be that you are missing some dlls like AWSSDK.StorageGateway.dll

Comment: What's the actual S3 request you're sending? Do all requests fail or only a certain one? There was a bug in Ceph RGW about rejecting overly large requests in some cases.